# Commutator algebra in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity

How can we verify the result that

$$[f\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}]= f[\textbf{X}, \textbf{Y}] - \textbf{Y} \left( f \right) \bf{X}$$

Where:

f- Some function

$\textbf{X}, \textbf{Y}$ - Some vector fields

Comment: Can you explain your notation? I guess $fX$ denotes the function of directional differentials of $f$ according to $X$. But how do you mean $Y(f)X$?

Comment: Ah by that I mean the vector field $\textbf{Y}$ acting on $f$.